# Initialising a large dict with unknown keys? Is there a better way than this?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

So I have a list of around 75000 tuples that I want to push into a dict. It seems like after around 20,000 entries, the whole program slows down and I assume this is because the dict is being dynamically resized as it is filled.

The key value used for the dict is in a different position in the tuple depending on the data, so I can't just extract the keys from the list of tuples into list x and invoke d.fromkeys(x) to pre-initialise the large dict. I've tried put together a solution, but after the dict is evaluated by ast.literal_eval, all I get is a single {'None': 'None'} :/

My soln (which doesn't work).

```
    d_frame = '{'+('\'None\': \'None\',' * 100000)+'}'
    d = ast.literal_eval(d_frame)
```

Is there a builtin method for something like this..

Thanks,

EDIT: I realise the stupidity of my idea.. Obviously you can't have identical keys in a dictionary.... :/

Just to clarify, I have a list of tuples with data like this:

```
 (assembly,strand,start_pos,end_pos,read_count)
 key_format : assembly_strand_val ( where val = start_pos or end_pos depending on other factors )
```

Because I don't know the key until I evaluate each tuple, I can't initialise the dict with known keys so was just wondering if I can create an empty dict and then add to it.. It doesn't make sense to evluate each tuple just to build a list then create a dict then repeat tuple eval...

EDIT: I realized where the bottleneck was.. With each tuple, I was checking to see if the relevant key already exited in the dict, but I was using;

```
if key not in dict.keys():
    dict[key] = foo
```

I didn't realise this builds a list of keys everytime and could be replaced with the far more economical

```
if key not in dict:
   dict[key] = foo
```

Changing this resulted in a staggering increase in speed....

Comment: If you have 100K keys that are all identical, you're only going to get a dict with 1 entry, not 100K. Is that actually what you want?

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to write `'\'None\'… \'None\','`; just write `"'None': 'None',"`.

Comment: How does the key position in the tuple depend on the data? Any example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So I have a list of around 75000 tuples that I want to push into a dict.

Just call `dict` on the list. Like this:

```
>>> list_o_tuples = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd')]
>>> d = dict(list_o_tuples)
>>> d
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}
```

---

> The key value used for the dict is in a different position in the tuple depending on the data

That isn't demonstrated at all by the code you showed us, but if you can write an expression or a function for pulling out the key, you can use it in a dict comprehension, or in a generator expression you can pass to the `dict` function.

For example, let's say the first element of the tuple is the index of the actual key element. Then you'd write this:

```
d = {tup[tup[0]]: tup for tup in list_o_tuples}
```

---

> It seems like after around 20,000 entries, the whole program slows down and I assume this is because the dict is being dynamically resized as it is filled.

That seems unlikely. Yes, the dict is resized, but it's done so exponentially, and it's still blazingly fast at sizes well beyond 20000. Profile your program to see where it's actually slowing down. My guess would either be that you're doing some quadratic work to create or pull out the values, or you're generating huge amounts of storage and causing swapping, neither of which have anything to do with inserting the values into the dict.

At any rate, if you really do want to "pre-fill" the dict, you can always do this:

```
d = dict.from_keys(range(100000))
for i, tup in enumerate(list_o_tuples):
    del d[i]
    d[list_o_tuples[0]] = list_o_tuples[1]
```

Then the dict never has to resize. (Obviously if your keys overlap the ints from 0-99999 you'll want to use different filler keys, but the same idea will work.)

But I'm willing to bet this makes absolutely no difference to your performance.

---

> I've tried put together a solution, but after the dict is evaluated by `ast.literal_eval`, all I get is a single `{'None': 'None'}`

That's because you're creating a dict with 100K copies of the same key. You can't have duplicate keys in a dict, so of course you end up with just one item.

However, this is a red herring. Creating a string to eval is almost never the answer. Your big mess of code is effectively just a slower, less memory-efficient, and harder-to-read version of this:

```
d = {'None': 'None' for _ in range(100000)}
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
d = dict([('None', 'None')] * 100000)
```

Comment: Cheers for your help. Still learning the basics as you can tell.